# How to access a private service in Symfony 5.3 phpunit tests?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I want to define a functional testcase for my phpunit-tests for my Symfony 5.3 application which requires the private service `security.password_hasher` from the container.

I get the following execption

> 1. `App\Tests\Functional\SiteResourceTest::testCreateSite`
>    **Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException**: The `security.password_hasher` service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead.

I followed the instructions from the documentation about [retrieving services in the test](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#retrieving-services-in-the-test)

What am i doing wrong? How can i fix this?

```php
class CustomApiTestCase extends ApiTestCase
{
    protected UserPasswordHasher $passwordHasher;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        // (1) boot the Symfony kernel
        self::bootKernel();

        // (2) use static::getContainer() to access the service container
        $container = static::getContainer();

        // (3) run some service & test the result
        $this->passwordHasher = $container->get('security.password_hasher');
    }

    protected function createUser(
        string $email,
        string $password,
    ): User {
        $user = new User();
        $user->setEmail($email);

        $encoded = $this->passwordHasher->hash($password);
        $user->setPassword($encoded);

        $em = self::getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        return $user;
    }


    protected function createUserAndLogIn(Client $client, string $email, string $password): User
    {
        $user = $this->createUser($email, $password);
        $this->logIn($client, $email, $password);

        return $user;
    }



    protected function logIn(Client $client, string $email, string $password)
    {
        $client->request('POST', '/login', [
            'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
            'json' => [
                'email' => $email,
                'password' => $password
            ],
        ]);
        $this->assertResponseStatusCodeSame(204);
    }
}
```

Comment: From the link you posted: If you need to test private services that have been removed (those who are not used by any other services), you need to declare those private services as public in the config/services_test.yaml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by making the service explicitly public in the `services_test.yaml`:

```yaml
services:
    Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasher:
        public: true
```

And then retrieving the service by its classname

```
$this->passwordHasher = $container->get(UserPasswordHasher::class);
```

Comment: Just be aware that by changing the service id you are actually going to have two instances of the hasher floating around.  Probably won't matter in this case but I think it might be best to use snake case here.  And a bit off-topic perhaps but it's a bit unusual to access the password hasher directly.  Usually you would access the UserPasswordHasher which in turn accesses the password hasher based on the type of user.

Answer (score 4):

I had to rewrite the complete definition of the service to prevent the following error during cache compilation:

> The definition for "security.user_password_hasher" has no class. If
> you intend to inject this service dynamically at runtime, please mark
> it as synthetic=true. If this is    an abstract definition solely used
> by child definitions, please add abstract=true, otherwise specify a
> class to get rid of this error.

**services.yaml**

```
security.user_password_hasher:
    class: Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasher
    public: true
    arguments:
      [ '@security.password_hasher_factory' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Symfony 6**

If you extend from `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;`

You can get the container and get the UserPasswordHasherInterface like this:

`$paswordHasher = static::getContainer()->get(UserPasswordHasherInterface::class);`

Also, you can get the entity manager or repositories:

```
$entityManager = static::getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();

$repository = static::getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager()->getRepository(Foo::class);
```

Answer (score 0):

A test kernel may also do the following:

```php
class PublicService implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        foreach ($container->getDefinitions() as $id => $definition) {
            if (stripos($id, 'whatEverIWant') === 0) {
                $definition->setPublic(true);
            }
        }
        foreach ($container->getAliases() as $id => $definition) {
            if (stripos($id, 'whatEverIWant') === 0) {
                $definition->setPublic(true);
            }
        }
    }
}

class AppKernel extends BaseKernel
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->addCompilerPass(new PublicService(), PassConfig::TYPE_OPTIMIZE);
        parent::build($container);
    }
}
```