# The definition for "security.user_password_hasher" has no class, during Symfony 5.3 phpunit tests?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony5

The question is somehow related to: [How to access a private service in Symfony 5.3 phpunit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68865038/how-to-access-a-private-service-in-symfony-5-3-phpunit-tests). I set up env `services_test.yaml` by:

```
services:
    security.user_password_hasher:
        public: true
```

When I try retrieve `security.user_password_hasher` I get exception:

```
$encoded = static::getContainer()->get('security.user_password_hasher')->hashPassword($user, $password);
```

> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\RuntimeException: The definition for "security.user_password_hasher" has no class. If you intend to inject this service dynamically at runtime, please mark it as synthetic=true. If this is an abstract definition solely used by child definitions, please add abstract=true, otherwise specify a class to get rid of this error.

Why I getting this exception? In the same test suite I retrieve `EntityManagerInterface::class` and everything is okay.

When I access `UserPasswordHasherInterface` (it's alias for security.user_password_hasher) in `dev` env by injecting it in controller `public function homepage(UserPasswordHasherInterface $hash)` no error is thrown. Why changing it settings to `public: true` crashing tests? It's that this service is special, and need special care in `test` env? Or maybe because `test` env change some defaults settings?

I'm newbie to Symfony. My guess is that container do some hidden magic. Someone can reveal the secret?
What does mean: [NOTE] The "security.user_password_hasher" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled?

Comment: There is a big section on the DI container in the docs.  Might be useful to browse through.  In your case you want to create your own public alias of UserPasswordHasherInterface to override the existing private one.  The docs cover the distinction between public and private which in turn explains the 'removed or inline' notice.

Comment: You right, there is a lot about DI. I will back to it tomorrow.